# SQL datediff for row items

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

I found difficulty with writing SQL statement to calculate the time of each items of row.

My table structure is simple:

```
TblProduct(Product nvarchar(50), Serial nvarchar(50), Time_Checked datetime)
```

Below is  my sample data:-

```
PRODUCT1 Serial1 2014-04-02 07:01:21.000
PRODUCT1 Serial2 2014-04-02 07:02:21.000
PRODUCT1 Serial3 2014-04-02 07:03:21.000
PRODUCT2 Serial1 2014-04-02 08:01:21.000
PRODUCT2 Serial2 2014-04-02 08:02:21.000
PRODUCT2 Serial3 2014-04-02 08:03:21.000
PRODUCT3 Serial1 2014-04-02 09:01:21.000
PRODUCT3 Serial2 2014-04-02 09:02:21.000
PRODUCT3 Serial3 2014-04-02 09:03:21.000
PRODUCT1 Serial4 2014-04-02 10:01:21.000
PRODUCT1 Serial5 2014-04-02 10:02:21.000
PRODUCT2 Serial6 2014-04-02 10:03:21.000
```

I want to calculate the time for changing product by `datediff(minute,start time, end time)`
where start time as the last item of each series of product kinds

Start time: `PRODUCT1 2014-04-02 07:03:21.000`

End time:  `PRODUCT2 2014-04-02 08:01:21.000`

==>`datediff(minute,start time, end time)=58 minutes`

Finally, I want to return a result like a table below:-

```
PRODUCT1 Serial3 PRODUCT2 Serial1 58(minutes)
PRODUCT2 Serial3 PRODUCT3 Serial1 58(minutes)
PRODUCT3 Serial3 PRODUCT4 Serial4 58(minutes)
```

Comment: is it sql server 2012 or 2008 or you want a solution which can be compatible with both?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e92e1/1) is a solution which can work on sql server 2008 as well as 2012 :

```
;WITH cte_temp
     AS (SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER()
                  OVER (
                    ORDER BY Time_Checked) AS rownum
         FROM   TblProduct)
SELECT t1.Product,
       t1.Serial,
       t2.Product,
       t2.Serial,
       Datediff(MINUTE, t1.Time_Checked, t2.Time_Checked) AS DiffInMinutes
FROM   cte_temp t1
       JOIN cte_temp t2
         ON t1.rownum + 1 = t2.rownum
WHERE  t1.Product <> t2.Product
```

query in `cte_temp` will assign an incremental number to each row in ascending order of `Time_Checked` and self joining result of `cte_temp` on `t1.rownum + 1 = t2.rownum` will match current row with next one. in the end, `where` clause will filter out the desired rows.

Note : if you are using sql server 2012, same thing can be done using `lead()` or `lag()` function.